# Can I hardcode the Eclipse DDMS location?

Tags: android, eclipse, ddms

I'm building Android apps which use location information, in the UK. Every time I start developing I have to remember to go into the DDMS perspective and edit + send new Longitude and Latitude data to be something relevant for the UK. Currently these are set to -122.084095 and 37.422006 respectively (yes, Google HQ).

I thought I would be able to edit .android/ddms.cfg, but they are not preset in that file.

Does anyone know if it's possibly to override the default values permanently, without resorting to Mock location applications etc., so that I don't have to do this daily?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Why not use [Mock Locations](https://developer.android.com/training/location/location-testing.html)?

Comment: Didn't know it existed. But looking at it, it would be re-coding a live app, which means I usually break something else, so more testing, testing, testing etc. I thought it would be more beneficial for all my apps and my future if I could override defaults from Google.

Comment: In the end, there's no substitute for testing on an actual device. Could you just use `avd geo fix` and put a little bash-script or batch file at your fingertips?

Comment: Yes, I could, but that's no different in reality to changing the values in DDMS on Eclipse startup. Question might be better put as "Can I extend Eclipse/DDMS to use different values in location controls?"